Switching Nextjs-build to Docker in Azure
we are moving from "static" HTML content to Docker in our Azure environment.
The pipeline build is yaml-based. The application is a NextJs one. The web code was previously loaded to a Container in an Azure storage account.
Now, when moving to Docker, and reading Microsofts pages about this, some questions arise:

Do I have to create a new pipeline of "Docker type"? Does that give some "magical" effect to it?

Can I continue to use the existing Container? They tell me I should create an "Azure Container Registry", is that something I need to do?


BR Dan



Do I have to create a new pipeline of "Docker type"? Does that give some "magical" effect to it?


AFAIK, There is no need to create a new pipeline of docker type if your project is available in local device


Can I continue to use the existing Container? They tell me I should create an "Azure Container Registry", is that something I need to do?


You can't use existing container,
I have deployed nextjs default app using Azure Container registry.
Steps :

Note :- Docker engine or Docker Desktop should be installed in your system to run docker command


Create a Azure Container Registry.



Enable Admin user.



Build you image using Dockerfile using command docker build -t imagename:tagname path/to /dockerfile. use . if Dockerfile is available in same path.



Login to your Azure Container Registry using command az acr login -n <container-registry-name>.



Tag you local image name to your Registry using command docker tag nextjs:latest vivek.azurecr.io/azurenextjs:latest and Push your image to registry using command docker push vivek.azurecr.io/azurenextjs:latest.




Create container web app and select Azure Container registry and select your Registry name, image and tag.




Make sure ports are similar on which container is listening. you can change port from Deployment Center -> <container-name (main)> option in web app. It takes some time to load the update.


Dockerfile:
FROM node:lts-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install && npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]


OUTPUT:

